# How To Store Incoming Call in Android

Tags: android

I want to know is there any way to store an incoming/Outgoing voice call in android.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: if your question is less than 100 words, you have not written a long enough question.

With that in mind, it is unclear what you mean by "store an incoming/Outgoing voice call".

If you are simply looking for a log of calls made by the device, check out `android.provider.CallLog`.

If you are looking to record the actual call itself (local voice and remote voice), that is not possible in Android, as the call audio information is handled outside of Android itself.

If you are interested in something else entirely, either edit your question to include more details, or start a new question with more details, so that we can understand what it is you are asking.

Comment: Hi ,I ended up in finding this,and tell your response sir

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.AudioSource.html#VOICE_DOWNLINK